# Stuck in log in screen after installing AMD-gpu-pro

Tags: drivers, 16.04, login-screen, amd-graphics

I was trying to find graphic drivers for my AMD Radeon 8570, when I came along
http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMDGPU-PRO-Install.aspx .I followed the steps and installed the amdgpu- pro , changed the usermod and rebooted. Since then , I can't log in on my accounts. Whenever I try to log in , a window *system program error detected* pops up and then I am kicked of to log in screen again. I tried to uninstall the drivers but there is not a amdgpu-pro-uninstall file/script. Any ideas ?

EDIT:
Fixed it , I mistyped uninstall in my path. I will leave this here , with the solution

Comment: Did you ever get a fix to this?

Comment: I had a similar problem and the cause was having both my Rx 480 and the integrated graphics card enabled. I disabled the Intel graphics at the BIOS and was able to boot normally.

Answer (score 1):

Same thing over here with a R9 M275. I did uninstalled, just go to console and issue the command amdgpu-pro-uninstall. It was available from me on my path.